# KeyError: <class '__main__.STAGE1'>

Tags: python, class, oop, tkinter, tk-toolkit

The code below shows a chemistry quiz application that contains a series of pages, where the user can switch across those pages.

```
class STARTPAGE(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        Instructions1 = tk.Label(self, text=("You will obtain a Desired Product that is chosen randomly from a Starting Reactant."))                                                      
        Instructions2 = tk.Label(self, text=("You get 3 Attempts to complete the question in which Points will be added to your score "))
        Instructions3 = tk.Label(self, text=("After 3 attempts you will be moved onto next stage or question"))
        Instructions4 = tk.Label(self, text=("You need to select one Reagent and 1 or 2 Conditions to complete stage"))
        Instructions5 = tk.Label(self, text=("Your score will be ranked among others in your same class in a leaderboard"))

        Instructions1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        Instructions2.grid(row=1, column=0)
        Instructions3.grid(row=2, column=0)
        Instructions4.grid(row=3, column=0)
        Instructions5.grid(row=4, column=0)

        StartQuiz = tk.Button(self, text="Start Quiz", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(STAGE1))
        StartQuiz.grid(row=8, column=1)

class STAGE1(tk.Frame):
     def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        Stage1 = tk.Label(self, text="STAGE 1")
        Stage1.grid(column=1, row=0)          
        #Explain the Main class and tk frame constructor in each class from stack overflow         
        self.ButtonData = BUTTONDATA(self, tk.Frame)  

        self.ButtonData.ReagentOption1.config(command=lambda: self.AllocatePointsStage(1))
        self.ButtonData.ReagentOption2.config(command=lambda: self.AllocatePointsStage(1))
        self.ButtonData.ReagentOption3.config(command=lambda: self.AllocatePointsStage(1))
        self.ButtonData.ReagentOption4.config(command=lambda: self.AllocatePointsStage(1))

        self.ButtonData.ConditionOption1.config(command=lambda: self.AllocatePointsStage(1))
        self.ButtonData.ConditionOption2.config(command=lambda: self.AllocatePointsStage(1))
        self.ButtonData.ConditionOption3.config(command=lambda: self.AllocatePointsStage(1))
        self.ButtonData.ConditionOption4.config(command=lambda: self.AllocatePointsStage(1))

        self.ButtonData.ReagentOption1.grid(column=2, row=5)
        self.ButtonData.ReagentOption2.grid(column=2, row=6)
        self.ButtonData.ReagentOption3.grid(column=2, row=7)
        self.ButtonData.ReagentOption4.grid(column=2, row=8) 

        self.ButtonData.ConditionOption1.grid(column=10, row=5)
        self.ButtonData.ConditionOption2.grid(column=10, row=6)
        self.ButtonData.ConditionOption3.grid(column=10, row=7)   
        self.ButtonData.ConditionOption4.grid(column=10, row=8)

        self.Continue = tk.Button(self, text="Continue", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Stage2))
        self.Continue.grid(column=6)

        self.QuestionStarter = QUESTIONSTARTER(self, tk.Frame)
        self.QuestionStarter.PointsLabel.grid(row=0, column=6)
        self.QuestionStarter.AttemptsDisplayed.grid(row=1, column=7)
        self.QuestionStarter.WordedQuestion.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.QuestionStarter.AttemptsDisplayedText.grid(row=1, column=8)
        DesiredProductLabel = tk.Label(self, command=lambda: ShowDesiredProduct(DesiredProduct))
        DesiredProductLabel.grid(row=5, column=0)

     def ShowDesiredProduct(self, DesiredProduct):
        DesiredProduct = GetDesiredProduct()
        return DesiredProduct

class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Chemistry Quiz")
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}

        for F in (STUDENTLOGINPAGE, STAFFLOGINPAGE, STARTPAGE, ASSIGNMENTPAGE, STAGE1, STAGE2, STAGE3, STAGE4, STAGE5, LEADERBOARDPAGE):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

            self.show_frame(STUDENTLOGINPAGE)
            if self.frames == []:
                print ("Error in loading program")
            #This class inherits from Tk class within module of Tk Inter
            #This basically displays each page in turn from the List

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise() 

    def get_page(self, page_class):
        return self.frames[page_class]
```

For some reason, I get the following error, which occurs within my show frame for stage 1:

```
Error -Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/ammarhusain/Desktop/Computing Project/Ammar Chemistry Program FINAL.py", line 316, in <lambda>
    StartQuiz = tk.Button(self, text = "Start Quiz", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(STAGE1))
  File "/Users/ammarhusain/Desktop/Computing Project/Ammar Chemistry Program FINAL.py", line 3152, in show_frame
    frame = self.frames[cont]
KeyError: <class '__main__.STAGE1'>
```

Comment: What is STUDENTLOGINPAGE?

Comment: That is another class which is a page for Student Login i coudn't put it up cause of space @VMAtm

Comment: The first step to debug a KeyError is to print out the keys from the dictionary immediately before the code that throws the error, to verify that the keys you _think_ are in the dictionary are actually in the dictionary. You should also verify that `cont` contains what you think it contains.

Comment: Oh ok how do i test that there is something in the cont in my code ? @BryanOakley

Comment: You can use a print statement: `print(cont)`

Comment: @BryanOakley Do i print this cont somewhere in my code cause if i do it in the shell it wont be defined

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're using the class definition as a key:

```
# add the frame
self.frames[F] = frame
# show the frame
self.show_frame(STUDENTLOGINPAGE)
```

I suggest you to use strings as a key in dictionary, and move out these lines out of loop:

```
self.show_frame(STUDENTLOGINPAGE)
```

Now back to your stacktrace, you have this line there:

```
controller.show_frame(STAGE1)
```

So, controller doesn't contain `STAGE1` screen on time the button was clicked. If you show the `STUDENTLOGINPAGE` **after** all the screens being created, the problem should go out:

```
# create all the screens
for F in (STUDENTLOGINPAGE, STAFFLOGINPAGE, STARTPAGE, ASSIGNMENTPAGE, STAGE1, STAGE2, STAGE3, STAGE4, STAGE5, LEADERBOARDPAGE):
    frame = F(container, self)
    self.frames[F] = frame
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

# check the sreens availability
if self.frames == []:
    print ("Error in loading program")

# now show the login form
self.show_frame(STUDENTLOGINPAGE)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for helping but I still dont understand what you mean  when you say put the key into strings and show STUDENTLOGINPAGE after all screens @VMAtm Also can i contact you about other problems in my program that would be amazing!!

Comment: About strings - it's just an advice, as doing the dictionary keys as classes is not a good readable practice. About `STUDENTLOGINPAGE` - you show it in your loop: `self.show_frame(STUDENTLOGINPAGE)`, before you've created all the screens. Move it out from `for`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Ahh ok I see but when I run my program now it brings up the Assignment Page screen instead of the StudentLogin page first? And when i use controller to move from assignmentpage to stage 1 it brings the same error. Can i contact you in anyway about this it will b very helpful @VMAtm

Comment: `ASSIGNMENTPAGE` is created **before** the `STAGE1`. Look at the error. It says that the dictionary can't find the `STAGE1`. It happens because you still didn't create it and didn't added it to the dictionary. Create all forms, only after that show any of them.

Comment: But i have created the class Stage 1 and I have put this class in my for loop too?

Comment: ^ look above i have created STAGE1

Comment: Your error means that the `STAGE1` can't be found, so you didn't create properly, as your code tries to show that page **before** it's been created.

Comment: can i contact you @VMAtm

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think that I've answered your question. It looks like you just don't understand some simple things about your program and the dictionaries. It's hard to help you remotely.

Comment: Ive fixed it now thanks but i want to cnatact you about other things of my program plz @VMAtm